# laptop ASUS P551CA shutting down

Tags: laptop

I have an ASUS P551CA-SX313D laptop bought 2-3 months ago.

Last days/week after I turn it on (after 1-2-3 hours) it suddenly become incredibly slow (almost stuck) and if I continue using it, it shut downs. I saw a bit the CPU temperature how it was and I saw that between 60-65c degrees it turns off.

Have you an idea what can be the cause? I've searched for rootkits too just in case, but nothing was found.

I thought that might be wifi or opera issue but I think happens also when I don't touch them.

Comment: Sounds like it could be hardware related.  I'd imagine it's still under warranty, no?  Try running one of the diagnostic tools that came with it -- maybe one one of the disks that came with it, or on one of the bootable partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the laptop internal cooling fans are malfunctioning

To ensure this,

1. Run multiple applications and high CPU Usage Games on your laptop and get your ear close to air vent available on your laptop
2. You will be able to hear the air coming out of vent

If this is not happening then the cooling fans are not working.  Then you need to manually clean the dust and fix the fan to get this resolved. If your laptop is under warranty better take it for a service.